# Check if an array contains several elements at once in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have 2 elements for example 1 and 2.
I need to find out if both of these elements are in my array.

For example:
I have 1,2,3,4. And i have Array [2,3,4,111].
If all my elements are in the array, then it's True, else False

Comment: you can use `all()`

Comment: @AvivYaniv it should be `all()`

Comment: @deadshot Thank you, I was confused!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array = [2,3,4,111]

elements_to_check = [2,3]

result = set(elements_to_check).issubset(array)

print(result)
```

Prints `True` if elements_to_check = [2,3]

Prints `False` if elements_to_check e.g. = [2,3,5]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
list = [2,3,4,111]
elements_to_check = [1,2]

result = len([x for x in elements_to_check if x in list]) == len(elements_to_check)
```

Prints True if elements_to_check = [2,3]

Prints False if elements_to_check e.g. = [1,2]